# How to set up options for a mini-panel (getting 'undefined index' error)?

Tags: 7, theming

This might be a tough question, sorry, but I am really struggling here.

The scenario is this: There is a series of similar mini-panels on my site that are being used as menus. I want to add an optional attribute (`autoheight`) to the html of these menus, operated by a check box via the back end.

Here's what I have done so far by Googling and blundering my way through:

In the .module file I added:

```
function foundie_add_menu_settings(&$form, &$form_state) {
//OTHER SETTINGS
$form['foundie']['autoheight'] = array(
     '#type' => 'checkbox',
     '#title' => t('Autoheight'),
     '#description' => t('Make drilldown menus adjust height automatically'),
     '#default_value' => $form_values['autoheight'],
   );
}
```

This seems to work fine - I can see the checkbox.

In the theme's template.php file, in the preprocess function for the menu element I have:

```
function foundation_preprocess_menu_block_wrapper(&$vars) {
  $settings = variable_get('foundie_block_menu_block_' . $vars['config']['delta']);
  if (empty($settings)) {
    if (!isset($vars['config']['style'])) {
      return;
    }
    $settings = $vars['config'];
  }

  $breakpoints = foundie_get_theme_setting('foundie_breakpoints', array(
    'small' => 'Small',
    'medium' => 'Medium',
    'large' => 'Large',
  ));
  $vars['content']['#tooltip'] = $settings['tooltip'];
  $vars['content']['#autoheight'] = $settings['autoheight']; //<--I ADDED THIS
  $vars['content']['#hover'] = $settings['hover'];
  $vars['content']['#style'] = $settings['style'];
  dpm($vars);
  foreach ($breakpoints as $breakpoint => $dimension) {
    $vars['content']['#' . $breakpoint] = $settings[$breakpoint];
  }
```

To me, that looks fine. It should be adding the value from the .module checkbox to the $vars which will then be processed and placed in the element (as far as I can tell).

I am getting the error:

> Notice: Undefined index: autoheight in
>   fcl_foundation_preprocess_menu_block_wrapper() (line 410 of
>   /var/docroot/web/docroot/sites/all/themes/custom/fcl_foundation/template.php).

Obviously, I am missing something here though. Would anyone be able to point me in the right direction? I think I am missing a step or something.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: What do you get when you dpm($settings) after this line `$settings = variable_get('foundie_block_menu_block_' . $vars['config']['delta']);`

Comment: @longboardnode ah! I do not see my autoheight var in this

Comment: gotcha, so what is the dpm result? I think either your autoheight isn/t saved when the mini panel is created, or it is stored somewhere else in $vars['config']. I'd do a dpm of vars['config'] to find out.

Comment: did you figure this out?

Comment: @longboardnode no I didn't I had to pass that ticket on to someone else :(